# Python sleep() function not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, sleep

I'm trying to use the sleep function to have a delay between iterations in a loop but the loop executes all at once without delays.

```
from time import sleep


for i in range(5):
    print (i)
    sleep(0.5)
```

I tried doing it without a loop and the same problem, prints all the text instantly:

```
from time import sleep

print('hi')
sleep(2)
print('hi')
sleep(2)
print('hi')
sleep(2)
```

Edit: The issue is indeed output buffering. Adding sys.stdout.flush() after every print line fixed the issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce…this puts a short delay between the prints in both v3 and v2.7 for me.

Comment: No it doesn't! Time your code using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) and you will see it takes 6 seconds

Comment: It's working for me, but in definitely doesn't take 6 seconds @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: Why ? The sleep is for a total of 6 seconds right, so it should take 6 seconds?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Could there be something wrong with my output console then? because I'm definitely seeing the output come all at once after a delay

Comment: @AlanNavai There is definitely some crucial information missing from your question.

Comment: @DavidCullen Apologies but I don't know much about this issue. I'm looking into the output buffering solution.

Comment: @AlanNavai You haven't supplied the operating system. You haven't described your runtime environment. Based on the limited information you've supplied, no one is going to be able to reproduce this problem.

Comment: @DavidCullen Yes, my bad. Anyways, the problem was the output buffering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because of output buffering. You can find the solution here: [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering)

Answer (score 1):

```
        for i in range(5):
            print(i)
            sleep(5)
```

do it like this, it is working in my side

Comment: How is this different from the code posted in the question that the OP say is *not* working?

Comment: It is working coz, you need to increase the time

Comment: I'm getting the same problem with this code

Comment: Can you show the error log?

Comment: @mamuncode The other answer was right, it has to do with the output buffering. Adding the line sys.stdout.flush() between print statements fixed the issue.